Upload pdf file to GCS with REST API - Coldfusion
I'm trying to upload a pdf file to GCS REST API with Coldfusion. My code is as follows. I get the same error every time. When I try a png file instead of a pdf, it works fine.
<cffunction name="uploadFileToCloudStorage" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="bucket_name" default="" />
    <cfargument name="object_name" default="" />
    <cfargument name="object_location" default=""/>
    <cfargument name="object_content_type" default="application/pdf" />
    <cfargument name="access_token" required="true" />
        
    <cffile action="readBinary" file="#arguments.object_location#" variable="fileContent">
        
    <cfset endpoint = "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/#arguments.bucket_name#/o?name=#arguments.object_name#&uploadType=media" />

    <cfhttp result="result" method="POST" charset="utf-8" url="#endpoint#" timeout="60">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="#arguments.object_content_type#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #arguments.access_token#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#fileContent#" />
    </cfhttp>
    <cfreturn replace(serializeJSON(result), '//', '') />
</cffunction>

The result is:
{
    "Mimetype": "Unable to determine MIME type of file.",
    "Errordetail": "I/O Exception: Received fatal alert: record_overflow",
    "Filecontent": "Connection Failure",
    "Statuscode": "Connection Failure.  Status code unavailable.",
    "Responseheader": {},
    "Text": true,
    "Charset": "",
    "Header": ""
}

for the first time. If i try again, the result is:
{
    "Mimetype": "Unable to determine MIME type of file.",
    "Errordetail": "I/O Exception: Connection reset",
    "Filecontent": "Connection Failure",
    "Statuscode": "Connection Failure.  Status code unavailable.",
    "Responseheader": {},
    "Text": true,
    "Charset": "",
    "Header": ""
}

I tried base64 and the result is the same. I tried read instead of readBinary with cffile and the result is still the same.

Can you post a call to the function for a PDF and one for a PNG? Also, those variables should be var or local scoped inside the function. local.fileContent, local.endpoint, and local.result.

When i post png file with image/png object_content_type, it works fine, application/pdf is still giving same error.

Try uploading a PDF and running this function on the file to see what it returns. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/filegetmimetype.html

It returns application/pdf

Do you have a link to the API documentation for this REST API? I found one that requires a PUT and one that requires a POST. Both have some other required fields that I don't see in your request. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload

I use this one: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object REST.

Have you tried posting the same files using the CURL example from your link?

It is about TLS problem. I posted answer of this question below.

It is a TLS problem. When I add these two lines of code, it worked:
<cfset security = createObject("java", "java.lang.System") />
<cfset security.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2") />

Full code:
<cffunction name="uploadFileToCloudStorage" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="bucket_name" default="" />
    <cfargument name="object_name" default="" />
    <cfargument name="object_location" default=""/>
    <cfargument name="object_content_type" default="" />
    <cfargument name="access_token" required="true" />

    <cfset fileContent = FileReadBinary('#arguments.object_location#') />
    
    <cfset endpoint = "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/#arguments.bucket_name#/o?uploadType=media&name=#arguments.object_name#" />

    <cfset security = createObject("java", "java.lang.System") />
    <cfset security.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2") />
    
    <cfhttp result="result" method="POST" charset="utf-8" url="#endpoint#" timeout="60">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #arguments.access_token#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="#arguments.object_content_type#" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#fileContent#" />
    </cfhttp>

    <cfreturn result />
</cffunction>


How did you uncover this was the issue? Which versions of ColdFusion and Java are you using?

I found it while researching the record_overflow error. It was written that there might be a TLS problem. I tried it and it worked. It is working now. CF: 2021, Java: 13

Have you applied all of the updates? This one specifically addresses the TLS issue. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2021-update-2.html
